# How to get values from "Tags box"

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have the following code for the "Tag boxes":

HTML:

```
<div id="tags">
   <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Add a tag" />
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#tags input').on('focusout',function(){
        var txt= this.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9\+\-\.\#]/g,'');
        if(txt) {
            $(this).before('<span class="tag">'+ txt.toLowerCase() +'</span>');
            $(this).before('<input>').attr({
                type: 'hidden',
                name: 'tags[]',
                value: txt.toLowerCase();
        }
        this.value="";
    }).on('keyup',function( e ){
    if(/(188|13)/.test(e.which)) 
        $(this).focusout();
    });
    $('#tags').on('click','.tag',function(){
        $(this).remove(); 
    });
});
```

I'm using hidden inputs to send tags to server. After clicking the submit button, form redirects me to another .php page. I'm trying to access on the php side with `var_dump($_POST['tags']),`but the result is array (size=1)
  0 => string '' (length=0).

Can anybody help?

Comment: Why do you tag `PHP` ?

Comment: @Hassaan because I wanted to use php to solve it

Comment: `e.which` contains a number, not a string, so using `.test()` on it won't work. Use `e.which === 13 || e.which === 188` instead.

Comment: @Mottie actually it worked, i have another problem))

Answer (score 0):

You can use a hidden inputs to send tags to server, this won't make any inputs visible on page, but will be sent when you submit the form.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#tags input').on('focusout',function(){
        var txt= this.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9\+\-\.\#]/g,'');
        if(txt) {
            $(this).before('<span class="tag">'+ txt.toLowerCase() +'</span>');
            $(this).before('<input>').attr({
                type: 'hidden',
                name: 'tags[]',
                value: txt.toLowerCase()
            });
        }
        this.value="";
    }).on('keyup',function( e ){
    if(/(188|13)/.test(e.which)) 
        $(this).focusout();
    });
    $('#tags').on('click','.tag',function(){
        $(this).remove(); 
    });
});
```

And then access on the php side like `var_dump($_POST['tags']);`.

Comment: I just tried, but when I try to print $_POST['tags'], it's "Array" instead of my tag.

Comment: Use `var_dump($_POST['tags'])`, it can contain multiple tags. Print shows you only the type of variable in this case. Or you can use `foreach ($POST['tags'] as $tag) print $tag;`

Comment: it prints array (size=1) 0 => string '' (length=0) :(

Comment: Looks like `txt.toLowerCase()` might be empty, change `value: txt.toLowerCase()` to `value: 'test-value'` and see what server returns in this case.

Comment: Update the answer with a reduced test case example of your webpage please, looks like the problem is in another place.

Answer (score 0):

You do it on the server side. If PHP is your server-side language, then yes you do it in PHP not Javascript. Your `<input>` tag needs to have a `name` attribute, otherwise the data in that field isn't going to get submitted.

If the form method is GET then your PHP script should find the value in the $_GET array. If it's POST then it will be in the $_POST array. The actual code to save it into your database depends on several factors, including whether you're using plain vanilla PHP or some MVC framework, what database you're using, the specific db configs and names of your data structures, etc. If you provide more of those details, somebody would probably be able to answer with specific code.